# Android App connecting to mysql server is returning values enclosed in [] , {} and double quotes

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

I have a developed a small app that connect to a remote mysql database in order to return information from it. I am basically using a php file that is located on the same server as the mysql database; the php file returns data based on the user response from the app. Here is how it looks (except for the credentials):

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost" ,"my_user","my_password");
mysql_select_db('my_db'); 
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

on Android side the code looks like this:

```
package com.example.maltinololperson.asynctask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ReadWebpageAsyncTask extends Activity {
  private TextView textView;
  InputStream is = null;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
  }
  private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        //the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));
        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.org/getAllPeopleBornAfter.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

               // Log.i("log_tag","Line reads: " + line); 
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        //parse json data
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               // Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                  //  ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                  //  ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                   // ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                //);
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
      return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);
    }
  }
public void readWebpage(View view) {
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
task.execute();
 }
}
```

Everything works fine, the app seems to connect to the server flawlessly, but the only issue is that the data returned (on the device-simulated) is in the form of: **[{"id":"1200","name":"John smith", "Sex":"m","birthyear":"1980"},{"id":"7110","name":"Batman":,....}]**, I wanted it to look like this: **id : 1200, name: john smith, sex: m, birtheyear: 1980** and so on. Since I am new to Android development and JSON, I can't figure out a way to accomplish that, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [URL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) This is what exactly you need to study. Refer it and let me know if you have more doubts. Its a great tutorial for beginners